# Using a yaml array with helm template

Tags: templates, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a directory structure representing a Helm chart as follows:

```
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
templates/
  template.tpl
```

values.yaml:

```
foo: ["bar", "baz"]

FOO:
 - BAR
 - BAZ
```

templates/template.tpl:

```
thing1: {{ .Values.foo }}
thing2: {{ .Values.FOO }}
```

Output of running `helm template .` in this directory. (Helm version v3.6.3)

```
---
# Source: test/templates/template.tpl
thing1: [bar baz]
thing2: [BAR BAZ]
```

You can see here that both thing1 and thing2 map to YAML arrays containing one string each, namely the strings `"bar baz"` and `"BAR BAZ"`.

I would like the items in the array to still be separate stings after templating. But the built-in functions that I have found in the helm template language documentation (like `{{ list .Values.foo }}`) don't do anything productive.

Can someone point me at how to properly template YAML arrays of strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Helm uses Go templates and Go templates doesn't know YAML. Thus it will just emit the *sequence* (YAML doesn't have arrays) in Go's default format, which happens to be `[<item> ...]`.

You need to tell Helm to convert the values to YAML format:

```yaml
thing1: {{ .Values.foo | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
thing2: {{ .Values.FOO | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

`toYaml` does the actual conversion ([see docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list#:%7E:text=toYaml)), `nindent 2` adds a line break and then indents every line 2 spaces. This is important when `toYaml` chooses to render your input as multiple lines, which you don't have any control over.

Comment: Just suprised, that a YAML file needs to be converted `toYaml` :/

Comment: @lucasvc `.Values.foo` isn't YAML, it's a native Go value that happens to be loaded from YAML.

Comment: ~~Aren't they loaded from the `values.yaml` file?~~ Sorry, now I see that the other is a `templates/template.tpl` - which also are at the end [YAML-files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/).

Comment: @lucasvc YAML is a serialization format. A value „being YAML“ means that it is text that adheres to the YAML syntax. The only operation defined on YAML is deserialization into native values. Querying fields like `.foo` is then done on those native values, not on the original YAML input. `.Values.foo`, for example, is a value of type `[]string`. Sure it came from YAML, but that is not information available at this point.

Comment: Regarding the docs, the linked github issue points [here](https://github.com/nofearOnline/helm-www/blob/703ede4ee92cee302c7783c316f05f276f38cc38/content/en/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list.md) which states: *toYaml: Convert list, slice, array, dict, or object to indented yaml, can be used to copy chunks of yaml from any source. This function is equivalent to GoLang yaml.Marshal function, see docs here: https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal*

Comment: @OhadSchneider Shame that this hasn't made it into the [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) yet. **Edit:** Never mind, it did. I'm blind.