# No help topic error for urfave/cli application when running in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We've written a lightweight cli wrapper for handling database migration using `urfave/cli`. It's working fine as a standalone app. But if I want to run it as a kubernetes job it's failing. This is my pod configuration for commands:

```
command: ["./migrator"]
args: ["up", "--db-from-env", "--source=file://./migrations"]
```

But the pod is outputting this error: `No help topic for 'up --db-from-env --source=file://./migrations'`.

It seems it's taking the whole string as the command. If I only pass the `up` command without the flags, it's working as expected by printing an error about the required flags and also the help prompt for the command.

```
command: ["./migrator"]
args: ["up"]
```

How do I pass the flags to the command?

EDIT:

Template for the helm chart:

```
{{ if .Values.migration.enabled }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.migration.image }}
          command: {{ .Values.migration.command }}
          args: {{ .Values.migration.args }}
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ .Values.envConfigMapName }}
{{- end }}
```

Corresponding values:

```
migration:
  enabled: true
  name: migrator
  image: registry.local/migrator:latest
  args: ["up", "--source=file://./migrations", "--db-from-env"]
```

Comment: That YAML list syntax looks correct.  You're not running this through something like a Helm chart that might be reformatting the `args:`?  Do you have a more complete Job YAML?

Comment: Running using helm.

Comment: Are these `args:` directly in the `templates/deployment.yaml`, or are you passing them via Helm values?  What does the actual template code look like?  (Can you [edit] the question to include these details?)

Comment: Just expanding `.Values.migration.args` gives you a default syntax from the Go text/template language, which happens to be valid YAML but isn't what you want.  [Using a yaml array with helm template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933283/using-a-yaml-array-with-helm-template) seems to have a pretty clear explanation of how to use `toYaml` here.